# Delete a particular entry from history in 'react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

consider this scenario. The user moves from Page1(/page1) to Page2(/page2) to page3(/page3) . now if he press the back button obviously he will go to Page2(/page2).

But here how can I delete the Page2(/page2) entry from history so that he will be taken to the Page1(/page1) on back button click from Page3(/page3)

Comment: At what point do you know that you don't want to go back to page 2? Is it before you go to page 3, or is it after?

Comment: Once he reached Page3 : the back button press should take him to Page1 not Page2 - Basically skip the previous page.

Comment: Yes, but do you know this only after getting to page 3? Or do you know it when you are on page 2?

Comment: Yes, We know that at page2. It's actually for a password reset flow.  Page1 is "Enter Mobile Number" , page2 is "Enter OTP", page3 is "setting new password". Once the user entered OTP and reached page3, on back click he should be taken back to 'Enter Mobile Number Page". That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you don't want to go back to page 2, you can replace page 2 in history when you leave for page 3. You can do this using [`<Link to={url} replace />`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/replace-bool) if there is a link, or you can use [`history.replace(url)`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#history.replace). (You can `import history from 'history'`, it is a subdependency of 'react-router-dom'.)

If you only know that you don't want to go back once you reach page 3, I don't know of any clean way to remove a previous entry in history.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And this wors perfect. But there is another issue once I reach Page1 from Page3 (skipping Page2), on browser next button click,  Its going to page3. That should not too happen, Is there any way to clear the history enries after the present one?

Comment: What does the next button do? Prever a link with a url over using history.next if you want predictable behavior.

Comment: Perhaps you should make a new question with that to make a detailed explanation of how to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Use `history.replace(page3)`.
It will insert page 3 in place on page 2. If you go back it will take you to page 1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And this wors perfect. But there is another issue once I reach Page1 from Page3 (skipping Page2), on browser next button click,  Its going to page3. That should not too happen, Is there any way to clear the history enries after the present one?